# Understand a weird method of calculus

Tags: calculus, soft-question, numerical-methods

I see [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MRD5yxkqus4) method of calculus on youtube and my question: is this method  valid? How we can understand it? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method is entirely valid! The problem is that it becomes rather impractical for digits greater than say $4$. Also it may not be very practical for numbers with many digits in them.

Let me try to explain the method.

### Basic principle: parallel lines crossing

If $m$ parallel lines intersect $n$ parallel lines they will intersect in $m\cdot n$ points. So multiplying the digit $m$ with the digit $n$ will be equivalent to counting the number of intersection points of $m$ parrallel lines crossing $n$ parrallel lines.

This is easiest to see when they intersect at right angles or close to that.

### How the 1's places the 10's places etc. come into play

If we write for instance two $2$-digit numbers as $\newcommand{\red}{\color{red}}\newcommand{\blue}{\color{blue}}\red{10a+b}$ and $\blue{10s+t}$ so that $a,b,s$ and $t$ are the digits what we get when multiplying these will be
$$
\begin{array}{c:c:c}
\mbox{100's}&\mbox{10's}&\mbox{1's}\\
\hdashline
& \red{b}\cdot \blue{s} &\\
\red{a}\cdot \blue{s}&& \red{b}\cdot \blue{t}\\
&\red{a}\cdot \blue{t}&
\end{array}
$$
which can be seen from the basic algebra:
$$
(\red{10a+b})\cdot(\blue{10s+t})=100\red{a}\cdot \blue{s}+10(\red{b}\cdot \blue{s}+\red{a}\cdot \blue{t})+1\red{a}\cdot \blue{t}
$$
This can easily be extended to a larger scheme.

The rightmost intersecting lines will always be the product of the 1's places of the two numbers. The leftmost intersecting lines will always be the product of the $10^n$'s places for an $(n-1)$-digit number. If we multiply an $(n-1)$-digit number by an $(m-1)$-digit number the pattern is the same. The leftmost intersecting lines will be the $10^n\cdot 10^m=10^{m+n}$ place.

### An additional table for the general principle

The most simple examples will be multiplying numbers of the form $11111...$. A table showing which places will be multiplied could be written as follows:
$$
\begin{array}{c:c:c:c:c:c}
...&\mbox{10000's}&\mbox{1000's}&\mbox{100's}&\mbox{10's}&\mbox{1's}\\
\hdashline
...&&&&&\\
&\red{1}\cdot \blue{10000}&&&&\\
...&&\red{1}\cdot \blue{1000}&&&\\
&\red{10}\cdot \blue{1000}&&\red{1}\cdot \blue{100}&&\\
...&&\red{10}\cdot \blue{100}&&\red{1}\cdot \blue{10}&\\
&\red{100}\cdot \blue{100}&&\red{10}\cdot \blue{10}&&\red{1}\cdot \blue{1}\\
...&&\red{100}\cdot \blue{10}&&\red{10}\cdot \blue{1}&\\
&\red{1000}\cdot \blue{10}&&\red{100}\cdot \blue{1}&&\\
...&&\red{1000}\cdot \blue{1}&&&\\
&\red{10000}\cdot \blue{1}&&&&\\
\end{array}
$$
where the red numbers show which places from the first number we multiply and the blue numbers show which places from the second number we multiply.